# CSS round div fill-in on hover

Tags: css

I tried to make a little effect while hovering a round div, but I couldn't find how actually to make the  fill in in a round shape too.

As you can see the fill in is in a square shape, and I would like to have it in the shape of my div (round in this case)
Is there a solution to that in CSS?

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 35px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size .5s, color .5s;
  background-size: 0 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/

Comment: thank you for the link @Nimish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) or [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow?v=control)

- box-shadow

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 35px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  background: blue;
  transition: box-shadow .5s, color .5s;
  background-size: 0 0;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px white
}

.circle:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px white;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

- radial-gradient

```css
.circle {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 35px;
        border: 3px solid blue;
        background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center , blue 50%, transparent 50%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        transition: background-size .5s, color .5s;
        background-size: 0 0;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        border-radius: 30px;

    }

.circle:hover {
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples. The first one is not practical as I need the inside of the circle to be empty, not filled with white so I couldn't apply it. Also why you have to set up the background size to 200% and there is two times `background-image` ?

Comment: @crisscross the radial-gradient only covers 50% of the bg ( see the rule: `blue 50%, transparent 50%` you can tune these values) Else, set bg-size at 100% and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can fill the circle and set animations with a pseudo element.

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.circle:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But the position absolute and relative messes up my other divs in the same container. Nice one though

Comment: The code likely can be tweaked If you can make a jsfiddle demo to show it.